# bootstrap 4: d-lg-flex in column (td)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table where some columns needs to be hidden on smaller screens, so I have the code as below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Normal 1</td>
    <td class="d-lg-flex d-none">hidden 1</td>
    <td class="d-lg-flex d-none" >hidden 1</td>
    <td class="d-lg-flex d-none">hidden 1</td>
    <td>Normal 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that on the large screen the 3 columns with 'd-lg-flex d-none' are shown as 3 rows in a column instead of 3 separate columns.

Need help on how to make them show normally on large (lg) screen size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `d-lg-flex` to `d-lg-table-cell`. This should work:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Normal 1</td>
    <td class="d-lg-table-cell d-none">hidden 1</td>
    <td class="d-lg-table-cell d-none">hidden 1</td>
    <td class="d-lg-table-cell d-none">hidden 1</td>
    <td>Normal 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bfse58ta/1/

Answer (score 1):

By default, **`display`** of `td` elements is **`table-cell`**. **`d-none`** change display of them to **`none`**. To reset display of them  on large screens, use **`d-lg-table-cell`**

```css
.d-lg-table-cell {
  display: table-cell !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Normal 1</td>
    <td class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">hidden 1</td>
    <td class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">hidden 1</td>
    <td class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">hidden 1</td>
    <td>Normal 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```